# python xml ElementTree exception for tag not found

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm using ElementTree to successfully pull values from specific tags in an xml file. To add some level of protection I'd like to throw and exception if a required tag is not present.

I found that ElementTree returns a value of "None" in place of a missing tag. But I can't even get that to work to my advantage :(

```
value = xmlTree.findtext('tag')
print value
```

Will print 'None" if the tag "tag" isn't present.

So I tried

```
if value == "None":
    print "tag not present"
```

But for some reason it won't catch it???

My next thought was to see if ElementTree had a build in exception that would detect a missing tag, but had no luck with that either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"None"` <sub>(a string)</sub> is not the same as [`None`](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#None) <sub>(a constant representing the absense of a value)</sub>.